# Run script when audio starts playing

Tags: javascript

I've tried this so far:

```
var snd = new Audio('audio.mp3');
snd.play();

snd.play = function(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

But the `console.log()` part is never getting executed. What is the correct syntax/event to listen for?
I could not find any "played" event on W3Schools.

Comment: play() is a native function, redefining it doesn't sound like a good idea? What are you really trying to do here !

Comment: Attach to [`onplay` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Comment: when audio start playing i want to run some script, so what is the correct event to listen in order to run some script when the audio is start playing?

Comment: Also, http://w3fools.com/

Comment: ^^ What @NiettheDarkAbsol said, inline events starts with `on`, if that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: OMG, why i don't think of that :(. thanks, it work now. thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol